# It's possible to add css modifications to Wordpress admin panel?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm making a theme for wordpress and I don't know how to apply a custom set of css rules that will remain still when wordpress will get updated.
Is there any way that I can apply a css file using functions.php from my theme?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This kind of feature doesn't belong on `functions.php`. See: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

Create [your own plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and enqueue your custom CSS and Javascript files (normally, jQuery is quite useful and some nice effects can be added).

### `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Admin Styles
 * Description: Add custom CSS to Admin area
 * Version:     1.0
 * Author:      brasofilo
 * Author URI:  http://stackoverflow.com/users/1287812/brasofilo
 */

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'b5f_admin_enqueue' );

/**
 * Register and enqueue Scripts and Styles
 */
function b5f_admin_enqueue()
{
    wp_register_style(
        'b5f_admin_style', // Style handle
        plugins_url( '/my-plugin.css', __FILE__ ), // Style URL
        null, // Dependencies
        null, // Version
        'all' // Media
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'b5f_admin_style' );

    wp_register_script(
        'b5f_admin_script', // Script handle
        plugins_url( '/my-plugin.js', __FILE__ ), // Script URL
        array( 'jquery' ), // Dependencies. jQuery is enqueued by default in admin
        null, // Version
        true // In footer
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'b5f_admin_script' );
}
```

### `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.css`

```
h2 { font-size: 3em !important }
```

### `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.js`

```
// See: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $("div[id^='icon']").hide(); 
});
```

Check all WordPress available scripts: [Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress).